# Need 2 clicks to activate button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to earn Javascript, specifically how to add onclick events, and manipulate the DOM.

I set up a real world example on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Jpburns/full/jrrdpE/).

Squish your browser down and you get the classic "hamburger" menu at the top. This works fine except that (after refreshing page) I have to click the hamburger **twice** to get it to activate.

Here's the code:

```js
var hamburger = document.getElementById("burger"),
menu = document.getElementById("myMenu");


hamburger.addEventListener("click",function(e){ 
  if (menu.style.height==="0px"){
    menu.style.height="480px";
    hamburger.style.transform="rotate(90deg)";
  }else{
    menu.style.height="0px"; 
    hamburger.style.transform="rotate(0deg)";
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 13pt/130% 'Linden Hill', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  background: #BEDFFC;
  margin: 0;
}

#burger {
  display: none;
  color: #BEDFFC;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .25s;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  left:20px;
  top:10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav a {
  font: .9em 'Archivo Narrow', "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 12%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  color: rgba(122, 166, 216, 0.87);
  border: 1px solid rgba(220, 247, 253, 0.55);
  border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

nav a.current,
nav a:hover {
  color: #dbebf7;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #539fd9;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav {
    background: #265980;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 60px;
    transition: all.5s;
  }
  nav a {
    float: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: hsla(209, 78%, 93%,.75);
    width:100%;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  
  #myMenu {
    width: 75%;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 18px auto;
    padding: 0;
    transition: all .25s;
    overflow: hidden; 
  }
  #burger {
    display: initial;

  }
  #burger:hover{
    color:white;
  }
}
```

```html
  
<nav id="myNav">
  <div id="burger">&#9776;</div>
      <ul id="myMenu">
      <li><a href="#" class="current">menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" >menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="interactive">menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">menu 7</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Now, if I remove the conditional in the addEventListener block, and just change the style of the element, it works fine.

```js
var hamburger = document.getElementById("burger"),
menu = document.getElementById("myMenu");

//works, but doesn't toggle, of course...
hamburger.addEventListener("click",function(e){ 
    menu.style.height="480px";
   
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 13pt/130% 'Linden Hill', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  background: #BEDFFC;
  margin: 0;
}

#burger {
  display: none;
  color: #BEDFFC;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .25s;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  left:20px;
  top:10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav a {
  font: .9em 'Archivo Narrow', "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 12%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  color: rgba(122, 166, 216, 0.87);
  border: 1px solid rgba(220, 247, 253, 0.55);
  border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

nav a.current,
nav a:hover {
  color: #dbebf7;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #539fd9;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav {
    background: #265980;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 60px;
    transition: all.5s;
  }
  nav a {
    float: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: hsla(209, 78%, 93%,.75);
    width:100%;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  
  #myMenu {
    width: 75%;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 18px auto;
    padding: 0;
    transition: all .25s;
    overflow: hidden; 
  }
  #burger {
    display: initial;

  }
  #burger:hover{
    color:white;
  }
}
```

```html
  
<nav id="myNav">
  <div id="burger">&#9776;</div>
      <ul id="myMenu">
      <li><a href="#" class="current">menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" >menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="interactive">menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">menu 7</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Looking for a pure Javascript, non-jQuery answer here.

What the heck am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `menu.style.height` property is not initialized as `"0px"`, but `""`. Modifying your logic to include this case makes the toggle work as expected:

```js
var hamburger = document.getElementById("burger"),
menu = document.getElementById("myMenu");


hamburger.addEventListener("click",function(e){ 
  if (menu.style.height==="0px" || menu.style.height===""){
    menu.style.height="480px";
    hamburger.style.transform="rotate(90deg)";
  }else{
    menu.style.height="0px"; 
    hamburger.style.transform="rotate(0deg)";
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 13pt/130% 'Linden Hill', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  background: #BEDFFC;
  margin: 0;
}

#burger {
  display: none;
  color: #BEDFFC;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .25s;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  left:20px;
  top:10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav a {
  font: .9em 'Archivo Narrow', "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 12%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  color: rgba(122, 166, 216, 0.87);
  border: 1px solid rgba(220, 247, 253, 0.55);
  border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

nav a.current,
nav a:hover {
  color: #dbebf7;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #539fd9;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav {
    background: #265980;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 60px;
    transition: all.5s;
  }
  nav a {
    float: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: hsla(209, 78%, 93%,.75);
    width:100%;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  
  #myMenu {
    width: 75%;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 18px auto;
    padding: 0;
    transition: all .25s;
    overflow: hidden; 
  }
  #burger {
    display: initial;

  }
  #burger:hover{
    color:white;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="myNav">
  <div id="burger">&#9776;</div>
      <ul id="myMenu">
      <li><a href="#" class="current">menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" >menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="interactive">menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">menu 7</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your solution should fix things. See, I thought it was initialized when I defined it in the CSS. So is it because it isn't in utilized until it's named, or accessed? As a designer, this sort of thing baffles me.

Answer (score 2):

The initial height of the menu is *computed* as zero, but the initial value of the inline style's height property is an empty string (because you haven't set it).

So when you test:

> ```
> if (menu.style.height==="0px"){
> ```

the first time, you hit `else` and explicitly set it to `0px`.

The cleanest solution to this problem is to test for, and to add and remove, **class names** instead of directly manipulating the inline style.

Comment: Thanks for your consise answer. This is the sort of thing I'm constantly having problems grasping. So why isn't it set to "0" since it's defined that way in the CSS? I guess it doesn't exist until you ask its value with Javascript? Puzzled here...

Comment: @jamesBurns — Because the style.* properties map onto the *inline style* (i.e. the style attribute) not the computed style.

Comment: THAT makes sense. Thanks.